# MySQL create user and database privileges

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am trying to write a simple shell script to create new mysql user and database for this user. Since I don't want to do use mysql root account, I've created a new user (let's call him 'creator'). I gave him `INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, CREATE, CREATE USER, GRANT` privileges, but I can't grant access to create a database for the new user.

Script looks something like this:

```
myuser=creator
mypass=xxxx
dbuser=newuser
dbname=newdb

mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "CREATE USER '$dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpass';";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '$dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpass' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname ;";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname . * TO '$dbuser'@'localhost';";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;";
```

I get `ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'creator'@'localhost' to database 'newdb'`. When I login as 'creator', i get same errors which is odd since 'creator' has GRANT privilege.  So, what privilege is 'creator' missing ? I want him to have as minimal privileges as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is very straightforward. Look at the order of things:

```
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "CREATE USER '$dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpass';";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "GRANT USAGE ON *. * TO '$dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpass' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname ;";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname . * TO '$dbuser'@'localhost';";
mysql -u$myuser -p$mypass -rs -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;";
```

The first three(3) lines cannot be performed by `$myuser` because . A superuser (such as `root@localhost`) must perform the first three lines.

Here is something additional: Only `root@localhost` can perform `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`. However, it is not even necessary because the `GRANT` command internally performs `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

With these things in mind, this is how you can create new users with its own database:

```
rootuser=root
rootpass=rootpassword
myuser=creator
mypass=xxxx
dbuser=newuser
dbname=newdb

mysql -u$rootuser -p$rootpass -rs -e "CREATE USER '$dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpass';";
mysql -u$rootuser -p$rootpass -rs -e "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$dbpass' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;";
mysql -u$rootuser -p$rootpass -rs -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname ;";
mysql -u$rootuser -p$rootpass -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname . * TO '$dbuser'@'localhost';";
```

If you seriously do not want to user `root@localhost`, create the user as follows:

Step 01) As `root@localhost`, login to mysql and run

```
SELECT PASSWORD('creatorpassword');
```

This will return a 41-character MD5-like string.

Step 02) As `root@localhost`, login to mysql and run

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to creator@localhost IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '41-character MD5-like string';
```

This creates the user and sets his password. The first line `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0` simply prevents the command from being recorded in the binary logs if you have binary logging enabled.

Step 03) Remove the commands from the audit history of mysql.

Every time you login to mysql, the commands are recorded in a file called `.mysql_history`. Run ths

```
cd
vi .mysql_history
```

Once you enter into `vi`, run `/SELECT PASSWORD`, hit enter. This will place you at the line where the command to print the PASSWORD function from text was done. Simply hit `dd` and `ZZ`, and you are done.

Going forward, you can user creator@localhost with the same rights as root@localhost and you have hidden the password well. You will just have to maintain its integrity.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, based on the comments below, I think the issue is that the `creator` user doesn't have the permissions it's trying to grant to the `newuser` account.

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html),

> You cannot grant another user a
>   privilege which you yourself do not
>   have

So I understand your desire to have the `creator` account have as few privileges as possible, but that's not how the MySQL privilege model works; to GRANT ALL on newdb.* to newuser, creator will also need ALL on newdb.*, as well as GRANT privilege.

Comment: Im pretty sure im logged in correctly. Tried both shell and phpmyadmin..

Comment: show grants produces:GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE, RELOAD, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE VIEW, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'creator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2EA417AC557EDC669453727C84FF5B4AC8C58529' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: OK, then from shell, could you confirm that you can do a mysql -u creator -pMYPASSWORD and confirm that you can connect correctly.

Comment: v1:~# mysql -ucreator -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 901128
Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny3 (Debian)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON newdb . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost'
    -> ;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'creator'@'localhost' to database 'newdb'

Comment: could you try, as mysql root, GRANT ALL ON newdb.* to 'creator'@'localhost'; , then see if that changes the output of (a) SHOW GRANTS FOR 'creator'@'localhost' and (b) the GRANT ALL you reference in the above comment?